# SQL Server XML query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I haven't dealt with XML documents since college. I'm looking for some assistance. I need to write a XML query in SQL Server that will output the data as such.

Please note that the data is being pulled from just one table in SQL Server.

```
<EnrollmentRequest>
    <Vendor id="string"/>
    <Members>
        <Member>  -- 1st Member Record
            <PayerPatientId>string</PayerPatientId>
            <PayerInsuranceId>string</PayerInsuranceId>
            <RequestTypeId>6427</RequestTypeId>
            <LastName>string</LastName>
            <FirstName>string</FirstName>
            <Gender>string</Gender>
            <DOB>string</DOB>
            <Zip>string</Zip>
            <Phone>string</Phone>
            <SSN>string</SSN>
            <City>string</City>
            <State>string</State>
            <DateOfServiceRange/>
            <PatientConsent>string</PatientConsent>
        </Member>
        <Member> -- 2nd Member Record
            <PayerPatientId>string</PayerPatientId>
            <PayerInsuranceId>string</PayerInsuranceId>
            <RequestTypeId>-2065</RequestTypeId>
            <LastName>string</LastName>
            <FirstName>string</FirstName>
            <Gender>string</Gender>
            <DOB>string</DOB>
            <Zip>string</Zip>
            <Phone>string</Phone>
            <SSN>string</SSN>
            <City>string</City>
            <State>string</State>
            <DateOfServiceRange/>
            <PatientConsent>string</PatientConsent>
        </Member>
    </Members>
</EnrollmentRequest>
```

I tried using

```
FOR XML PATH('Member'),  
ROOT('EnrollmentRequest')
```

But I am unable to get the 'Members" element piece. It's my understanding there cannot be more than one root, so how can I get the 'Members' tag to function like the "EnrollmentRequest' tag and how can I get the vendor id tag to appear only once in the file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a sub-select for your member info - something like this:

```
SELECT 
    'abc' AS 'Vendor/@Id',
    (SELECT
        m.ID,
        m.LastName,
        m.FirstName,
        m.ZIP,
        m.City
    FROM 
        dbo.YourMembersTable m
    FOR XML PATH('Member'), TYPE) AS 'Members'
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('EnrollmentRequest')
```

This enumerates all the members, outputs each in a `<Member>` element, and then "wraps" this into a `<Members>` element inside the `<EnrollmentRequest>` root element.

Comment: That did it.  i was in XML hell, thank you it Worked!

Comment: @teck_neck123: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.